# Not recognizing parameters when importing data into SQL DB

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc

I have a dataframe(df) with 9 columns:

```
 Pos  Qty  Price  Auction    tID      Date     From  To   Currency
 23   50   0.03    IFA2       DN   2018-07-03   FR   GB      EUR
```

When trying to insert it into my DB I keep getting this error message:

('The SQL contains 9 parameter markers, but 7 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Sometimes it says 4, 1, or 0 parameters were supplied.

This is my code:

```
finalData = df.values.tolist()
inputQuery = "INSERT INTO TABLENAME ([Product], 
[Quantity], [Price], [Auction], [tID], [Date], [From], 
[To], [Currency]) \  
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

cursor.executemany(inputQuery, finalData)
```

Why is it only recognizing 7 parameters when I can see that 9 is provided?

Comment: you are using `executemany` - so you probably have more then one row? do _all_ rows of your whole `df`have 9 values? are there `NaN`/`None` in the df? check `print(all( len(x)==9 for x in finalData))` or smth alike `badData = [x for x in finalData if len(x) != 9]`

Comment: I do not have more than one row in this example but the code should be able to handle more than one more row if needed

Comment: When checking print(all( len(x)==9 for x in finalData)) it returnes "True"

Comment: Why not just use [df.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)?

Comment: When trying that I keeps getting this error message: ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'BIGINT'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)") [SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE [[temp].[Damas_Multi_Capacities_ACT]] (\n\t[index] BIGINT NULL, \n\t[Product] BIGINT NULL, \n\t[Quantity] BIGINT NULL, \n\t[Price] FLOAT(53) NULL, \n\t[Auction] VARCHAR(max) NULL, \n\t[TraderID] VARCHAR(max) NULL, \n\t[DeliveryDate] DATE NULL, \n\t[CapFrom] VARCHAR(max) NULL, \n\t[CapTo] VARCHAR(max) NULL, \n\t[GivenCurrency] VARCHAR(max) NULL, \n\)\n\n']

Comment: Your original INSERT solution assumes that the table already exists, so you could use `if_exists='append'` in your `to_sql` call to avoid trying to re-create the table.

Comment: You also need to supply the schema name separately, e.g.,  `schema='temp'` and *not* include square brackets around the table or schema names.